# Cannot Select div's after insert via JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, maps, arcgis

I have a descriptions for each layer of a map , being generated via JSON objects. I generate all html for these containers, which contains maps , legends, and descriptions.

```
html_description += '<div ' + hide + ' id="'+ map_div_id + '_description_' + id + '">' + layer_info.description + '</div>';

 // Set the description from the layer info
 $('#' + map_div_id + '_description').html(html_description);
```

Then I want to only show certain descrptions (depending on which layer is showing). So below should work , (as it works in my console debugger) .

```
 // Hide Descriptions 
 $('#' + map_div_id + '_description div').hide();
 $('#' + map_div_id + '_description_' + visible).show();            

 // Show Proper Description
 console.log('#' + map_div_id + '_description_' + visible);
 console.log($('#' + map_div_id + '_description_' + visible));
```

Also the odd thing is I can manipulate the heading contanier :

```
// THIS WORKS?!
$('#' + map_div_id + '_description').hide();
```

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/PazSs/2/

Comment: Here is a fiddle , lots of code not needed but didn't have time to remove it yet. http://jsfiddle.net/PazSs/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the jsFiddle.

I modified it to investigate, and here's my copy:

http://jsfiddle.net/PazSs/8/

I do believe your problem is in your `dynamic_layer` array. I stepped through the code in jsFiddle and that array has zero elements.

The result is when you call

```
dynamic_layer[map_div_id].setVisibleLayers(layer_id);
```

It crashes, as you're dereferencing an undefined result (null).

I see you're populating the `dynamic_layer` further above:

```
if (typeof geo_server != 'undefined' && geo_server != null) {
  gp_server = gis_server + '/' + geo_server;
  gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor(gp_server);
} else {
  // Adds a dynamic layer
  dynamic_layer[map_div_id] = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(full_map_server);
  map[map_div_id].addLayers([dynamic_layer[map_div_id]]);
}
```

This seems to be the only place you stuff objects into the `dynamic_layer` array, so I'd start there. Check out your logic and ensure that you always put the layer in when required.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It helped, It was because my dynamic layers weren't fully renderd, adding them to onlayers complete, it worked.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help you hunt this down.

Answer (score 0):

that selector:

```
$('#' + map_div_id + '_description div')
```

would look for a div inside your description div.

assumed the value of 'map_div_id' is 'test' your markup after insert should look like this:

```
<div id="test_description">
  <div> ...your description here </div>
</div>
```

when i see how your build your html_descriptions string, it does not look like it is doing that... (it only would be like that if 'layer_info.description' would contain '...'

thats a lot of assuming, it's probably easier you show us some generated markup, and complete script. use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Im not sure you want to see over 600 lines of code.

$('#' + map_div_id + '_description div')
would look for a div inside your description div.

That is correct , hiding all divs below 

Markup would look like
http://bin.fuelphp.com/snippet/view/c2

Answer (score 0):

I can see your logic:

1. HIDE ALL layer descriptions
2. and then SHOW only the layers you want to see

What does "`visible`" mean? Is that an id? The name implies a boolean.

If it's a boolean, your selector

```
$('#' + map_div_id + '_description_' + visible).show();
```

doesn't look like it'll work properly.

Can you describe what `visible` is a bit more, please, and give examples of the actual markup?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and I agree with hereandnow78... jsfiddle can probably save us all a lot of time here.

Comment: O sorry visible is the id of the layer i want to show (bad naming convention) it should be layer_id